# Why does can the button no be re-enabled after being disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

This code intends to append numbers in a array to the string shown in a div after showing it in another div when one clicks a button. After clicking the button once, the number is shown correctly, but the button can not be clicked twice.

```js
var index = 1;
 var chartData = [103, 144, 142, 141]
 function update_num(index, l){
  console.log(l[index - 1])
  document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = l[index - 1] + ' MU';
  setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML = ' ';   
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML = document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML + ' ' + l[index - 1];   
  }, 1000);
 }

 function func_num() {
        var index = 1;   
  /*Define what should happen after the button is clicked*/
        document.getElementById("b").onclick = function(){

            var buttonB =  document.getElementById('b');
            buttonB.disabled = true;   
            if(index <= 2 ){
    update_num(index, chartData);
    if(index == 1){
     buttonB.innerHTML = 'Next Draw';
     buttonB.style.left ='405px';
    }
    index++;
    setTimeout(function(){
     buttonB.disabled = false;
     console.log('aaa ' + buttonB.disabled);
    }, 1000);
 
   } else if (index == 3){
    while (index < chartData.length){
     setTimeout(function(){update_num(index, chartData);}, 2000 * (index - manualClicks));
     index ++;
    }
    setTimeout(function(){buttonB.disabled = false;}, 1000);
    buttonB.innerHTML = 'To Task';
            }else{
                buttonB.style.visibility="hidden";
            }
   console.log('run6661' + buttonB.disabled);
            if(index == 3 ){
                setTimeout(function(){buttonB.innerHTML = 'Automatically Draw for {{ machine_cl }} times';}, forceToLookTime);
            }
        };
 }

   func_num();
```

```html
    <div id='canvas' style='position:relative;width:1305px;height:420px; margin: auto; margin-top: 20px;'>
<div>
        <button id='b'  type='button' style='visibility: visible; position: relative; left: 440px; top: 350px;'>Start</button>
        
        <div id='box1'  style='visibility: visible; position: relative; top: 300px; left: 40px; text-align: center;' >
        </div>
```

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. Line 2 of your HTML has `<div>` when you intended to have `</div>`. This means the button is inside the div, which you rewrite the innerHTML of. This means that `buttonB` no longer exists in the document when you try to stop it being disabled, but a clone of it does.

Answer (score 0):

From [SPEC](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute):

> **2.4.2. Boolean attributes**
>
> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Also:

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
>   To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
>   altogether.

That said, you MUST remove explicitly the attribute, like this:

```
document.getElementById('my_button').removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: The code in the question is not attempting to use `setAttribute("disabled", "false")`, it is using `.disabled = false`. The `disabled` DOM property **can** take `true` and `false` boolean values. It isn't an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code is totally fine, the problem is in the markup. You're opening the `<div>` tag, but not closing it properly, like `</div>`.

Change

```
<div id='canvas' style='position:relative;width:1305px;height:420px; margin:auto; margin-top: 20px;'>
<div>
```

to

```
<div id='canvas' style='position:relative;width:1305px;height:420px; margin:auto; margin-top: 20px;'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure @Quentin, makes sense. I have always wondered why so many people comment on the question, and not provide an answer, and now I know the reason. Thanks.